# How to Group Items in a Count statement

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a query that will return Total Claims reported in 0-3 days, 4-7 days, 8-14 days, and 15+

```
Select DATEDiff(DD,LossDate,DateReported) As TimeToReport,Count(ClaimId) As Num from LossRun
where PolicyNum='1234567890'
And PolTerm='201403'
Group By  DATEDiff(DD,LossDate,DateReported)
order by DATEDiff(DD,LossDate,DateReported);
```

---

This is what i get

```
TimeToReport NumofClaims
0   5
1   3
2   1
3   4
4   3
5   2
6   2
7   2
8   1
12  1
13  1
14  2
15  2
48  1
52  1
107 1
121 1
147 1
533 1
```

---

Basically i want to see the total for 0-3, 4-7,8-14,and the rest,,,, timeToReport

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. In order to get some help you need to provide some details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What's the question???  What's wrong with your current query???

Comment: And what's wrong with your result???  It seems like it's showing result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `SUM` with `CASW WHEN`

```
select 
    SUM(CASW WHEN TimeToReport <= 3 THEN NumofClaims ELSE 0 END) '0~3 day', 
    SUM(CASW WHEN TimeToReport >= 4 AND  TimeToReport <=7 THEN NumofClaims END) '4-7 days',
    SUM(CASW WHEN TimeToReport >= 8 AND  TimeToReport <=14 THEN NumofClaims ELSE 0 END) '8-14 days',
    SUM(CASW WHEN TimeToReport >= 15 THEN NumofClaims ELSE 0 END) '15+ day'
from (
    Select DATEDiff(DD,LossDate,DateReported) As TimeToReport,Count(ClaimId) As Num 
    from LossRun
    where PolicyNum='1234567890'
    And PolTerm='201403'
    Group By  DATEDiff(DD,LossDate,DateReported)
) t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,,,,,,, appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is going to be by creating your own temp table which includes the min and max for each bucket and then joining to it.

```
declare @t table (OrderedID int, EmpID int, EffDate date, Salary money)

insert into @t
values
(1,1234,'20150101',1)
,(2,1234,'20160101',2)
,(3,1234,'20170101',8)
,(4,1234,'20180101',15)
,(1,2351,'20150101',17)
,(5,1234,'20190101',4)
,(5,1234,'20190101',2)
,(5,1234,'20190101',9)

declare @Bin table (MinVal int, MaxVal int)

insert into @Bin
values
(1,3)
,(4,6)
,(7,9)
,(10,15)
,(15,20)
,(20,25)



Select
B.MinVal,count(T.EmpID) as EmpsInBin
From @t T
inner join @Bin B on T.Salary between B.MinVal and B.MaxVal
group by B.MinVal
```

Output

```
MinVal  EmpsInBin
1       3
4       1
7       2
10      1
15      2
```